# Is Ubuntu's default backup program good? What does it exactly do?

Tags: 16.04, backup

I would like to backup my entire Ubuntu system to a USB and have the ability to boot it up and install it on my hard drive. Is this possible? I want to have this available in case my current installation is compromised or crashes for some reason. I've took a look at Ubuntu's default Backup program found in the settings menu. I would like to use a easy to use GUI program than can meet my standards. I'm not very good at understanding terminal commands. The default program looks like its easy to use. Can I do the following above with this program or do I need something else? Thanks! :)

[image: Default backup program image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is backup the whole partition, where Ubuntu is installed. This can be done by clonezilla

http://clonezilla.org

It makes an iso file from your partition so you can restore it anytime from USB.

The step by step guide is here: 
http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible with the default backup program. I recommend using clonezilla, it has worked for me very well.

Comment: I won't be able to provide more details at the moment, when I get to my computer I can add more...

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at Clonezilla, thank you!